# Mutual Information

Tags: information-theory

Given $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, we have

\begin{align}
I(X_1,X_2;Y_1,Y_2) & = I(X_1;Y_1,Y_2) + I(X_2;Y_1,Y_2\mid X_1) \\[1ex]
& = I(X_1;Y_1) + I(X_1;Y_2\mid Y_1) + I(X_2;Y_2\mid X_1) + I(X_2;Y_1\mid X_1,Y_2) \\[1ex]
& \ge I(X_1;Y_1) + I(X_2;Y_2\mid X_1) \\[1ex]
& = I(X_1;Y_1) + I(X_1,X_2;Y_2) \tag a \\[1ex]
& \ge I(X_1;Y_1) + I(X_2;Y_2)
\end{align}

where equation (a) in the line before last follows by the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$. I don't understand this (a) part.

I can write $I(X_1,X_2;Y_2) = I(X_1;Y_2) + I(X_2;Y_2\mid X_1)$, but how does $I(X_1;Y_2)$ have anything to do with the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Comment: I think second term in second equation should be $I(X_1;Y_2 \mid Y_1)$, no? And first term of last equation should be $I(X_1; Y_1)$ ? Please recheck

Comment: You're right, I have made the changes to the question. Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: With the corrections, I can only agree with you - I don't understand how to get to eq (a), it looks wrong - unless we are missing some assumptions of the problem (perhaps $Y_i$ depends only on $X_i$ ?)

Comment: There's no mention of independence between $Y_i$ and $X_i$.

Comment: Are you sure? For example, that would make sense if $Y_1$ is the output of a channel with $X_1$ as input, and the same for $Y_2,X_2$...

Comment: Yeah. The question was "Label the statement with $=$, $\le$ or $\ge$". Justify your answer. $I(X^2;Y^2)$ vs $I(X_1;Y_1) + I(X_2;Y_2)$, if $p(x^2) = p(x_1)p(x_2)$

Comment: Do you mean if $Y_1$  is the output of a channel with $X_1$ as input, then they are independent? But why? Wouldn't they be related based on the channel?

Comment: If so, $Y_1$ depends "only" on $X_1$, and  if $X_2$ is independent of $X_1$, hence $Y_1$ is independent of $X_2$

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to obtain it in another way. From the third line, because $I(X_2;X_1,Y_2)=I(X_2;X_1)+I(X_2;Y_2|X_1)=I(X_2;Y_2|X_1)$ if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, thus we have $I(X_2;Y_2|X_1)\ge I(X_2;Y_2)$, which establishes the conclusion.

Comment: Is the line $I(X_1;Y_1)+I(X_1,X_2;Y_2)$ in the question used? It doesn't seem to be...
I understand your expansion of $I(X_2;X_1,Y_2)$, but did you get $I(X_2;Y_2|X_1)≥I(X_2;Y_2)$ by removing $X_1$ from $I(X_2;X_1,Y_2)$?

Comment: Yes, I did. That's because $I(X_1,X_2;Y_2)=I(X_2;Y_2|X_1)+I(X_1;Y_2)$, but it seems we don't know the dependence between $X_1$ and $Y_2$, thus I just tried another way.